# How should I deal my worker who is stealing my beauty products?

Tags: ethics, employer-relations, unprofessional-behavior, job-description, pakistan

I own a beauty salon and I have three workers who has been working for me for the last six years.However, one of them recently started stealing my beauty products from my salon.

Maybe she thought that I am unaware of her activity but a few days ago I checked my salon's camera footage and I found her stealing some of my beauty products.
She helped me whenever she found me in trouble. She also respects me a lot. Now I am in confusion as to what I should do now.

Should I tell her that I know all about her activity and terminate her from her job, or should I help her financially or fulfill her need so that she stops stealing my beauty products.

Comment: For a start, you shouldn't make assumption nor jump to conclusion. I would suggest asking to speak with her, only to learn what happened.

Comment: @Clockwork OP says they checked security footage. What assumptions do you think they're making?

Comment: @rath I don't know if seeing someone taking products through a camera is forcefully stealing. From my point of view, we're lacking information there...

Comment: @Clockwork Did you read the linked question? The situation is exactly the same - seeing security footage of someone remove money from a register

Comment: @DavidK I didn't read the linked question, since it was posted when I was posting my comment. Otherwise, I was simply replying to the first comment about assumptions.

Comment: @Clockwork What does forcefully have to do with it?  Stealing is take something you did not pay for.

Comment: @paparazzo What I was thinking is we lack information to judge whether or not it truly is stealing (e.g. if I were to talk about seeing a colleague taking something, it would sound like he's stealing; but if I try to look further, I'll realise he was putting things back to storage for example). But perhaps I'm thinking too far.

Answer (score 10):

If she's a valued employee, then give her a warning. You can't pretend it never happened. Just say you saw her on camera taking product, you'll cut her slack because you think of her as a friend, but friends don't steal from each other, don't do it again or you'll have to fire her.

This sometimes works, but keep your eyes open, sometimes once they get caught they go off the rails. I've seen a manager with a decade in a position try and burgle the shop after getting a warning.

> should I help her financially

No, not on a personal level, that turns you into a crutch and you don't owe her that.

A method I use which works well for workers experiencing temporary financial strain is I will advance them half their pay no questions asked if they want it before payday. And deduct it on the day.

Comment: +1 And if she's really a friend, maybe ask her why she felt the need to steal - no judgement, just out of concern. Maybe she's in a tough place financially (in which case you need to decide whether you can, or want to, help), maybe she is frustrated about something, maybe it's medical (either a compulsion, or something like dementia affecting her behaviour). Clearly you can't accept her stealing, but there are more positive ways to deal with it than simply firing her if she has been a valued employee/friend in the past.

Answer (score 2):

> Should i tell her that i know all about her this activity and
>   terminate her from her job

Yes. Stealing from the shop should be dealt with by firing. If you are absolutely sure she was stealing, you need to fire her.

When you talk with her, you can explain the seriousness of her actions, if you think she somehow didn't understand. And you can express sorrow that you have to fire her. If this is otherwise a good employee, you could offer to help her out financially while she finds her next job or even give her a good recommendation.

But she must be gone. Failing to do that sends the message that it's okay to steal from you, and you should expect more of the same.

> she also respects me alot.

She apparently doesn't respect you enough to avoid stealing from you.